# use a shell script to update version

Tags: linux, bash, shell

```
#include  "calcmarks.h"

// calcmarks, version 1, released Thu Mar 23 13:16:49 WST 2017

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int nmarks = 0;

    if(argc == 1) {
         nmarks += readmarks(stdin);
```

Don't care what this code is, what I want is a shellscript to update and version.After do the shellscript,the comment above will become

// calcmarks, version 2, released (time you execute the script)

Tried to do below which didn't work.

```
a=$(date) 
sed -i "_bak" s'/Thu Mar 23 13:16:49 WST 2017/$a/g' "calcmarks.c"
```

Comment: What did you try for yourself to solve this?

Comment: Have you investigated `sed -i` capability yet?

Comment: @Inian I know how to sed it using `sed -I  's`,  I can use it to place the version1 to version2 and also the time ,but what I want to is that change it every time I execute my script.

Comment: Please post your attempt to the question

Comment: @Inian.    `a=$(date)`   `sed -i "_bak" s'/Thu Mar 23 13:16:49 WST 2017/$a/g' "calcmarks.c"` .That didn't work, it will change the line into `// calcmarks, version 2, released date`

Answer (score 0):

Here is a list of commands that will perform the trick.
Nota : If you are using a different -version-numbering system (2.1, 2.1.1, etc), you'll need to change it slightly.

```
prev_version=$(sed -n '\%.*// calcmarks, version %!d;s///;s/ .*//p' "$file")
new_version=$((prev_version+1))
curr_date=$(date "+%a %b %d %H:%M:%S %Z %Y")
sed -i -e "s#\(// calcmarks, version \)${prev_version}.*#\1${new_version}, released ${curr_date}#g" "$file"
```

Comment: `grep | sed` is a [useless use of `grep`](http://www.iki.fi/era/unix/award.html#grep).  You want `prev_version=$(sed -n '\%.*// calcmarks, version %!d;s///;s/ .*//p' "$file")` etc.  Take note also of the absence of a `/g` flag on anything which only matches once, and proper quoting of the file name.